# Music organizer that lets you listen and separate the songs you like from a huge dump

Tags: music, media-manager

I've a huge collection of music and I've only ever liked a very tiny fraction of songs from it.

For example I have entire Albums when in fact I only ever liked just one song from that album (which is what made me download the whole album).

Softwares I've already tried:

- MPC

The way I listen to music now is just drag drop the entire music folder into my favourite music player - MPC, and skip any songs I don't like until I reach the one that I do.

I want an easier way to separate the songs the I like.

My current approach is cumbersome... when I reach the song in the playlist that I like, I open it's "properties", go to its path and the copy-paste that song in another folder.

This causes the following problem: After separating, say 100 songs like this, I now have to make a choice when I decide to listen to music the next time - should I listen to the 100 songs that I've separated, or should I continue where I left off and try to separate more songs? Which is a difficulty on its own since I don't remember where I actually left off. What ends up happening is I can't do either!

- Windows Media Player

There's an option in WMP Library to "star" a track. I don't like it for the reason that it doesn't seem to be of much use **outside** of WMP. I don't want the organizer to be the only software I could listen my music in.

Is there a software that would help me separate the songs in a more efficient manner?

Windows Freeware

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying [MusicBee](https://getmusicbee.com/). It let's you rate tracks and let's you create auto-playlists based on rating (among other criteria). You can also create an auto-playlist based on how many times you've skipped a track (e.g. you can have a playlist that excludes tracks that have been skipped more than 5 times).

Another feature I like is that it remembers your position on the currently playing playlist (aka the "playing tracks" panel). Keep in mind it forgets the position if you start playing a completely different playlist.

Alternatively, if you don't want to rate anything, just dump all your music into the "playing tracks" panel and remove stuff from there as you see fit, then save that as a playlist, and keep updating that playlist.

You can always export the playlist as a standard M3U file if you want to play it with another program.

Answer (score 0):

You could try mediamonkey, it lets you "RATE" your songs and the do bulk operations with their names,tags,folders etc depending on your criteria. you could for instance rate a song and run the script everytime you open it so your best rated songs are moved to a different folder.

Comment: Could you expand on the script?

Comment: check the wiki, this script is actually a builtin function
http://www.mediamonkey.com/wiki/index.php/WebHelp:Changing_Filenames/4.0#Auto-Organize_Files